# Adding emojis to standard list of emojis on keyboard using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to add emojis to the standard list of emojis on android and ios using codenameone

Here is the perfect example of what we would like to do, check it out

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snaps.kimoji&hl=en

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the app does and spending money on "that" is something I wouldn't do on principal ;-) But from the comments it looks like it isn't an actual emoji but rather simple gifs or images that are transferred to other apps (e.g. SMS) probably using copy/paste which you can do using a native interface.

Comment: he reckon she should be the next miss bum bum

Answer (score 1):

Small icons can attached in theme or it can be downloaded from server and store those in storage